# Copy child nodes with exeptions in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I think the main question is how write exeption expression to get rid of "S-3" and "Z" attributes in the output result. But how?

**source code**

```
<root>
  <B att-1="some value" att-2="value"> text 1 
    <S-1>text 2</S-1>
    <S-2>text 3</S-2>
    <S-3 trash-att="value"> trash-text a </S-3>

    <Z z-att="value"> z-text 1 </Z>  
 </B>

  <B att-1="some value" att-2="value"> text 4
      <S-1> text 5</S-1>
      <S-2> text 6</S-2>
      <S-3 trash-att="value"> trash-text b </S-3>

      <Z z-att="value"> z-text 2 </Z>  
  </B>

  <B att-1="some value" att-2="value"> text 7
    <S-1> text 8</S-1>
    <S-2> text 9</S-2>
    <S-3 trash-att="value"> trash-text c </S-3>

    <Z z-att="value"> z-text 3 </Z>  
 </B>

</root>
```

**desired output**

```
<root>
  <B att-1="some value"
      att-2="value"
      S-1="text 2"
      S-2="text 3">

    <Z attr=" z-text 1 "/>  
  </B>

  <B att-1="some value"
      att-2="value"
      S-1=" text 5"
      S-2=" text 6">

      <Z attr=" z-text 2 "/>  
  </B>

  <B att-1="some value"
      att-2="value"
      S-1=" text 8"
      S-2=" text 9">

    <Z attr=" z-text 3 "/>  
   </B>

</root>
```

my xslt code (S-3 and Z attributes are still in place, but shouldn't)
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


<!-- 1 - MAIN transform with element B -->
  <xsl:template match="B">
    <B>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="*" >
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </B> 
   </xsl:template>


 <!-- 2 - keep additional Z node -->  
   <xsl:template match="Z">
    <Z > 
  <xsl:attribute name="attr">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </Z> 
   </xsl:template>


  <!-- 3 - delete nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="S-1">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="S-2">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="S-3">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I will appreciate any solution

Comment: It is not clear which rules you want to implement but your `delete nodes` comment above templates that are not empty but instead apply-templates is odd. If you want e.g. `S-1` elements to be not processed at all then use `<xsl:template match="S-1"/>`. To add further elements to that "rule" use e.g. `<xsl:template match="S-1 | S-2 | S-3"/>`. But the whole template based approach is usually only meaningful and simple if you rely on it consistently and don't mix it with `for-each`; the use of `for-each` in the template for `B` and an `apply-templates` is likely not what makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for reaction. Have to think it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You Can Try This and use for-each**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="B"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="B">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[not(@*)]">
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Z"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Z">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="attr">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

DEMO:https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/2

Comment: that's nice version and it works, thank you. At first glance, I could not even understand where there is a restriction on the S-3 element. Suppose that is this fragment `<xsl:for-each select="*[not(@*)]">` ... But is it possible to modify this fragment with a direct pointing at specific element/elements exeption (exact S-3 for example)? Roughly speaking "*[not(S-3, Z, etc)]"?

Comment: use `<xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::S-3) and not(self::Z)]">`